# Limit web browser on iPad to a single web site (or a few specific sites)?

Tags: ipad, safari, accessibility, web-browser, web-browsing

I know that iPadOS provides the [Guided Access](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202612) feature to limit access to a single app.

Suppose that one single app is a web browser, either Safari or a third-party browser. Is there some way to limit the browser to a single web site? Or even better, a few specific sites in tabs?

I am trying to assist an elderly person who simply wants to read one or two or three particular newspaper/magazine sites. They have no other use for the iPad, and would be overwhelmed with navigating the usual iPad experience.

If links going outside my specified site could be suppressed, even better still. If not possible, then the Back button should take them back to the original web site I specified on that particular tab.

If Safari offers this kind of feature, great. If not, I would be happy to pay for a third-party browser you can recommend that supports this kind of keep-it-simple experience for people with physical or cognitive limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You could explore using [Firefox Focus](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/firefox-focus-privacy-browser/id1055677337) (see [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_Focus)), it has privacy and focus and it design goals, and does not support opening tabs at all.

It also does not store browsing history though, so that might be a downside.

Comment: And Firefox Focus has « shortcuts » instead of bookmarks. These appear when the user taps into the URL field of the nav bar, in a very simple obvious interface.